# Undesired Newlines in Output from AD Search

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am having an issue with the out put; I wanted a second look to see another way of getting my output to not have return or new lines in it.

Could someone take a look for me please?

```
$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=Workstations");

$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher;
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain;
$objSearcher.PageSize = 100000;
$objSearcher.SearchScope = "Subtree";

$dateMonth = Get-Date -Format "MM";
$dateDay = Get-Date -Format "dd";
$dateYear = Get-Date -Format "yyyy";

$colProplist = "name"
foreach ($i in $colPropList){$objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add($i)}

$colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll();

foreach ($objResult in $colResults)
    {

        $objItem = $objResult.Properties; 

        $computer = $objItem.name | Select-String -Pattern 'NSC';


        Write-Host $computer;

        #Add-Content "C:\PowerShell\Reports\Computer Report - $dateMonth-$dateDay-$dateYear.csv" "$computer";
    }
```

**Example output:**

```
NSCNPR02





NSCNPR05

NSCNPR01


NSCNPR03
```

**Expected Output:**

```
NSCNPR03
NSCNPR05
NSCNPR01
NSCNPR03
```

Comment: where is the problem? Add-Content?
if you want to avoid newlines you can do  Write-Host $computer -nonewline

Comment: The Add-Content is for the document. However, either or, the write line will also create the skip. There are 10000+ computers that I am filtering thru

Comment: There will be multiple lines not just one, it could be 1 - 100

Comment: Please provide an example of both expected and actual output.

Comment: I have added that for you. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$date = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy"
$filename = "C:\PowerShell\Reports\Computer Report - $date.csv"

...

$objSearcher.FindAll() | ? {
  $_.Properties.Name -like 'NSC*'
} | Add-Content $filename
```

The problem with your code is that

```
Add-Content "C:\Pow...csv" "$computer"
```

always adds a new line, even if `$computer` is `$null`. This behavior is due to the double quotes around `$computer`. Without them the problem wouldn't exist (but my suggestion would still be a cleaner solution ;).

Answer (score 0):

Add-Content adds new lines.
As a workaround you may out text into the string and then write it into the file when the cycle is done.

Comment: I am commenting it out. if I remove the write-host or add-content, the out put is all equal

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the LDAP filtering instead of pulling all the records and then searching?

Instead of

```
"LDAP://OU=Workstations"
```

Use

```
"LDAP://OU=Workstations?(&(objectCategory=computer)(name=NSC*))"
```

For more information: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx